# different ways to access webpage from server

Tags: html, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

To access any page from web server i am familiar with two ways as shown below

```
http://127.0.0.1/joomla30/efinanace/currently-no-jobs-available/index.php

http://127.0.0.1/joomla30/efinanace/index.php?value=currently-no-jobs-available
```

but the following way is new for me i.e. index.php is followed by path

```
http://127.0.0.1/joomla30/index.php/efinanace/currently-no-jobs-available
```

my question here is that how this above link is interpreted by index.php or how the server can determine which page is desired by user. . . . plz answer before down rating this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first way requires a .htaccess file, which actually rewrites the link to the latter format. In the latter format, the system will call the index.php to start loading the page. Everything after `index.php` is parsed as part of the query string, split on `/`, and routed to figure out what page you want.

The actual routing is basically starting at the left side of the url after index.php and trying to match it to menu aliases. (So in your case, it looks for a menu item with the alias efinanace. Finding that, it looks for an item under that called `currently-no-jobs-available`, to use your example.)

Once it has a menu item (and for no match, it just uses the default menu item). It then calls the component for that menu item and passes the rest of the query string to that component's router.php file (should be found in the base of the component). That file is then tasked with figuring out what the component should do based on the query string.

Obviously there is a lot more happening within all this, but that should give you a basic overview.